# Loop over tbody in Django views

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to loop over a `tbody` in my django views to get the data from the form but when i print the items in the tbody it only shows the last one

Here's the part I am trying to loop on

```
<tbody class="player-instances">

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="form-0-pname" id="id_form-0-pname"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="form-0-hscore" id="id_form-0-hscore"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="form-0-age" id="id_form-0-age"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="form-0-pname" id="id_form-1-pname"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="form-0-hscore" id="id_form-1-hscore"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="form-0-age" id="id_form-1-age"></td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
```

Views.py

```
if form.player_instances.cleaned_data is not None:
    for item in form.player_instances.cleaned_data:
        print("item", item)
        print("form.cleaned_data", form.cleaned_data)
        player = Player()
        player.pname= item['pname']
        player.hscore= item['hscore']
        player.age= item['age']
        player.save()
        team.player.add(player)
    team.save()
```

The output in terminal is the following:

```
item {'pname': 'tt22', 'hscore': 8, 'age': 89}
form.cleaned_data {'tname': 'tt1'}
```

Why is it overriding the first input fields despite having different id?

Answer (score 0):

Try different name in name field like : form-1-pname and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: I did that but still it's overriding the data